# Serial communication between linux and arduino

Tags: linux, arduino, arduino-c++

I'm trying to make a command line, from my computer to the ESP-32, and I don't want to depend on the arduino serial monitor for the interaction, so I'm trying to write a small application for communication. But it's not working, I based on this tutorial for the communication:
https://blog.mbedded.ninja/programming/operating-systems/linux/linux-serial-ports-using-c-cpp/
but, I don't see any output from the board.
this is my current code:

```
#include <fcntl.h>    //
#include <errno.h>    // THESE ARE THE LIBRARIES THAT WILL BE USED
#include <termios.h>  // FOR THE TERMINAL COMMUNICATION WITH SERIAL PORTS
#include <unistd.h>   //

#include "auxiliar.h"

std::string _OUT [28];

class _SERIAL_TERM_ {
    public:
        int _SERIAL_PORT_;
        int _drw_pointer = 0;
        struct termios tty;
        _SERIAL_TERM_(int); // INITIALIZE
        void fire_confg();  // CREATE CONFIG
        void fire_Print(std::string _msg);
        void fire_input(std::string _inp);
};

_SERIAL_TERM_ :: _SERIAL_TERM_(int _s){
    _SERIAL_PORT_ = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if(_SERIAL_PORT_ < 0){
        fire_Print("Could not connect ignite monitor to /dev/ttyUSB0");
        printf("Error %i from open: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    if(tcgetattr(_SERIAL_PORT_, &tty) != 0) {
        fire_Print("Serial communication failed on tcgetattr config.");
        printf("Error %i from tcgetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }
    fire_confg();
}

void _SERIAL_TERM_ :: fire_confg(){
  /*
   THIS IS THE TERMIOS BASIC CONFIGURATION
   I'D LIKE TO THANK mbedded.ninja FOR HIS ARTICLE
   TEACHING HOW TO CONFIGURATE THIS, IT WAS LITERALLY PAIN
   AND I COULDN'T FIND A GOOD INFORMATION SOURCE
   https://blog.mbedded.ninja/ <- visit his website
  */
  tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
  tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB; 
  tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; 
  tty.c_cflag |= CS8; 
  tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS; 
  tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL; 

  tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
  tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO; 
  tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHOE; 
  tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHONL; 
  tty.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;
  tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); 
  tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL);

  tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
  tty.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR; 

  tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;  
  tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

  cfsetispeed(&tty, B9600);
  cfsetospeed(&tty, B9600);
  if (tcsetattr(_SERIAL_PORT_, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
    fire_Print("Termios failed to configure basic settings :(");
    printf("Error %i from tcsetattr: %s\n", errno, strerror(errno));
  }
}

void _SERIAL_TERM_ :: fire_Print(std::string _msg){
    _OUT[_drw_pointer] =  _msg;
    _drw_pointer++;
    //std::cout<<"draw pointer"<<_drw_pointer<<std::endl;
    if(_drw_pointer >= 28){
        for(int i = 0; i < 28; i++){
            _OUT[i] = "";
        }
        _drw_pointer = 0;
    }
}

void _SERIAL_TERM_ :: fire_input(std::string _inp){
    unsigned char msg[256];                 // INITIALLIZE OUR BUFFER TO SEND THE DATA
    strcpy( (char*) msg, _inp.c_str() ); // COPY OUR COMMAND INTO THE BUFFER
    printf("{INPUT} write bytes. sent message: %s\n", msg);
    write(_SERIAL_PORT_, msg, sizeof(msg)); // WRITE TO THE SERIAL PORT (AS A FILE)
    memset(&msg, '\0', sizeof(msg));        // CLEAN MEMORY
    char _output[1024];                     // INITIALIZE OUTPUT BUFFER
    memset(&_output, '\0', sizeof(_output));// CLEAN OUTPUT BUFFER
    int num_bytes = read(_SERIAL_PORT_, &_output, sizeof(_output));  // READ THE BUFFER OUTPUT
    if (num_bytes < 0) {                                             // IF THERE ARE 0 BYTES IN OUTPUT
      fire_Print("ERROR: could not read output from serial port...");// PRINT ERROR
      printf("Error reading: %s", strerror(errno));                  // LOG ERR MESSAGE
    }
    std::string _out = atos(_output);
    printf("{OUTPUT} Read %i bytes. Received message: %s\n", num_bytes, _output);
    fire_Print(_out);
    //fire_Print(_inp);                       // PRINT OUTPUT
}

_SERIAL_TERM_ *_term = new _SERIAL_TERM_(9600);

std::string _my_input = "";
void FIRE_INPUT_KEYBOARD (unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    if(key != 13){
        _my_input += key;
    }else{
        _term->fire_input(_my_input);
        _my_input = "";
    }
}
```

And my ESP32 code is this:

```
int _RTOS_SHELL_UPDATE_ (){
    last_data = "";
    data = Serial.readStringUntil('\r\n');
    if(data.length() == 0){
        last_data = "";
    }else{
        last_data = _RTOS_CORE_EXECUTE_ (data);
        Serial.println("(Input command) root@phoenix>> " + last_data + " size: " + data.length());
    }
    return _RTOS_SUCCESS_; 
}
```

whenever I execute the code I get:

```
{INPUT} write bytes. sent message: kjknj
{OUTPUT} Read 0 bytes. Received message:
```

and whenever I try to write or read a file using the terminal it remains empty

I already tried to intercept the message using:

```
while true; do cat /dev/ttyUSB0; done
```

(it's for sure that its usb0, I tested with arduino IDE)

edit: if you need to test and compile the stuff here's the github repo of the current version:

https://github.com/Chocobonis/phoenix-OS

Comment: Does your ESP32 answer when you send data with tools like `picocom` or `minicom` from command line? If not, the problem is with your ESP32 code. Never do `cat /dev/ttyUSB0` or other actions with serial device if other program expect input: serial port is not atomic and requires exclusive access. Your ESP32 expect `"\r\n"` (btw, why in single quotes?). Are you sure you send `\r\n` from host?

Comment: The ESP32 is working, I tested it with the arduino IDE, using it's serial monitor, and the communication does work, but using, my own monitor, won't get data, I just tested just sending a message on loop, and whenever I send a message it just return 1 message with corrupted characters, and then it stops working

Comment: Do you close IDE's serial monitor before running your program? Do you configure serial port on ESP32 side to the same 9600 baud as in your program? (BTW, `s` parameter in constructor is never used). You use non-canonical mode with *MIN == 0, TIME == 0 (polling read)*, `read()` return immediately, even when no data is received. Read what these values mean in [man 3 termios](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html).

Comment: I'm aware of the useless value, and non-canonical mode, yes, I actually have to close arduino IDE before using the program, otherwise it won't start the serial port, but after using a serial monitor and my program at the same time, I noticed that write, does work, and the problem is mostly the reading part

Comment: regarding min and time, are on 0 because 10 is a lot of time, and even though i leave min on 0 and time in 10 i'll receive empty data

Comment: the fact of having min = 0 and time = 10, also leads to empty buffer being sent on the message

Comment: also when having VMIN to a non 0 value,  it basically gets stuck as no output is being received

Comment: What is displayed in IDE serial monitor when you send a message in serial monitor, when your program is not running?

Comment: when using the arduino IDE, i get my normal output from the commands, the problem doesn't seem to be the board, as it works perfectly with arduino IDE, while on the program i can write but i can't read, and the atos function it's just to convert from char[] to string, the output actually should be given in raw text by the esp32 using serial.println()

Comment: What baudrate is set in IDE serial monitor?

Comment: all my monitors have 9600

Comment: ESP32 program expects some line terminator (why `'\r\n'` as a single character? No warning from ESP32 compiler?) but string from host is not terminated with any special character. And why do you `write()` all 256 bytes of `msg` regardless of actual string length? Try to remove `write()` in your host program and run `read()` part in infinite loop. And in ESP32 program don't wait for intput but `Serial.println("Hello World")` right after serial port configuration. Then restart the board and check if host can read "Hello World".

Comment: i actually noticed that the problem is fetching back the response, as writing works properly

Comment: I did that with the serial thing, it gets some data, but it loses most of the stuff

Comment: Write a small simple standalone program which just initializes serial port and `read()` in a loop, something like this: `for (;;) { size_t ret = read(...); if (ret==-1) perror("read"); else if (ret > 0) printf("%zu bytes received\n", ret); }`. Modify your ESP32 program to write a string to serial port after startup unconditionally, e.g. every 1 second. Debug this combination first.

Comment: I made a separate thread with just while(1) and display stuff on the monitor, and it doesn't seem to get anything at all

Comment: well wrote a different program

Comment: now I can't upload anything or do anything

Comment: well the idea of making a separate application was terrible, now its not responding, can't even upload stuff despite the fact that I already rebooted the computer

Answer (score 0):

I reduced your program to minimal port initialization and simple read:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *device = "/dev/ttyUSB0";
    if (argv[1]) {
        device = argv[1];
    }

    int fd = open(device, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "open(%s): %s\n", device, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    struct termios tty;

    if (tcgetattr(fd, &tty) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "tcgetattr(%s): %s\n", device, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    tty.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    tty.c_cflag |= CS8;
    tty.c_cflag &= ~CRTSCTS;
    tty.c_cflag |= CREAD | CLOCAL;

    tty.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHOE;
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ECHONL;
    tty.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY); 
    tty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK|BRKINT|PARMRK|ISTRIP|INLCR|IGNCR|ICRNL);

    tty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
    tty.c_oflag &= ~ONLCR;

    tty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tty.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;

    cfsetispeed(&tty, B9600);
    cfsetospeed(&tty, B9600);

    if (tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &tty) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "tcgetattr(%s): %s\n", device, strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned char buffer[1024];

    for (;;) {
        ssize_t num_bytes = read(fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        if (num_bytes == -1) {
            if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EWOULDBLOCK) {
                continue;
            }
            fprintf(stderr, "read(%s): %s\n", device, strerror(errno));
            break;
        }
        if (num_bytes > 0) {
            printf("%zi bytes received:\n", num_bytes);

            for (ssize_t i = 0; i < num_bytes; ++i)
                printf(" %02X", buffer[i]);

            printf(" (");
            for (ssize_t i = 0; i < num_bytes; ++i)
                printf(" %c", isprint(buffer[i]) ? buffer[i] : '?' );

            printf(")\n");
        }
    }

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

Run minimal sketch on device:

```c
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello World!");
}

void loop()
{
}
```

Output after device start:

```
1 bytes received:
 48 ( H)
1 bytes received:
 65 ( e)
1 bytes received:
 6C ( l)
1 bytes received:
 6C ( l)
1 bytes received:
 6F ( o)
1 bytes received:
 20 (  )
1 bytes received:
 57 ( W)
1 bytes received:
 6F ( o)
1 bytes received:
 72 ( r)
1 bytes received:
 6C ( l)
1 bytes received:
 64 ( d)
1 bytes received:
 21 ( !)
1 bytes received:
 0D ( ?)
1 bytes received:
 0A ( ?)
```

This is just a proof of concept. Try to reproduce it first.

Of cource, the program consumes 100% CPU in polling read.  Simplest way to reduce CPU consumption is to remove `O_NDELAY` from `open()` flags and set `VTIME` to 1.

Comment: well after the ESP32 died (literally) I tried with MEGA2560 and it works fine, it seems as the actual problem is the configuration with the times I fetch the data or something, idk is this code tested on ESP32 or normal arduino??

Comment: aldo as it has a graphical interface I cant use for(;;) so That's why i added a class object (also to port it)

Comment: @bonii I run it with Arduino Nano clone (which was near at hand) plugged with cp210x USB-to-serial converter. I'm very surprised if ESP32 really died because of serial port communication, can't imagine how this is possible. Sorry if so.

Comment: Regarding `for(;;)`, this is only example. There are many ways how to integrate communication to an interactive application. You can call non-blocking `read()` periodically with period short enough not to lose data. Or call blocking `read()` in separate thread, or use multiplexing I/O (most right way, i think).

Comment: I don't have more devices, i'll have to wait until the new ESP32 arrives